# How to remove all Activities except root activity with launch mode and activity alias?

Tags: android, alias, launchmode

I'm studying launch mode intent flag and activity alias in Android programming.

There are activities (A - B - A - B) in back stack, and I want to start activity A and I also want to reuse A at bottom of back stack. So final state of back stack I want is just (A).

To do so, I write code like this

A (MainActivity)

```java
package com.example.intentflagexampele;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        });
    }
}
```

B (MainActivity2)

```java
package com.example.intentflagexampele;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        });

        findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(MainActivity2.this,
                    "com.example.intentflagexampele.SplashActivity");
            intent.setComponent(componentName);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        });
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.intentflagexampele">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.IntentFlagExample2">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity2"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        </activity>

        <activity-alias
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The problem is that whenever I start SplashActivity with button2, Back Stack become (A - B - A) not (A).

What should I do? Is there something wrong?

Comment: You can try finishAffinity(); and then startActivity(intent); finishAffinity will remove all the activites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a clean application architecture. In general, if you have multiple instances of the same `Activity` in the stack, you cannot reliably tell Android to go back to a **specific instance** of an `Activity`.

You should create separate activities so that you can avoid having multiples instances of the same `Activity` in the stack (if you want to be able to return to a specific instance of that `Activity`).

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(intent);
```

This will clear the back stack of activities.

Comment: Oh, It works partially, thank you =). But I can't reuse A. It was destroyed and recreated.